# The code I made in c# for threading wont run on unity

Tags: c#

This error pops every time I write the code for pipe spawn

> Assets\spawn.cs(1,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dataflow' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading.Tasks' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Here is the code for spawn.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject prefab;
    void Start()
    {
        

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

For context I'm following this tutorial : [yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtQMytORBmM&t=1632s)

I'm expecting to remove the error above `your text`

Comment: _["The TPL Dataflow Library (the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow namespace) is not distributed with .NET. To install the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow namespace in Visual Studio, open your project, choose Manage NuGet Packages from the Project menu, and search online for the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow package."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#creating-a-console-application)_.   Apart from the `using`, _**where is your actual TPL Dataflow code?**_

Comment: ...also `unityscript` is deprecated by Unity

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a need for System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, so you can remove that import.

Review his finished code if you get stuck: https://github.com/Britishgaming/GMTK-Unity-Tutorial

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can summarize source code more than I already did.